# Make variable return true only when the user holds the key down

Tags: javascript, pong

I'm recreating the classic pong game in Javascript and I have a loop that updates the game state then redraws the whole game.

Setting the height of the game:

```
var leftHeight = 225;
var rightHeight = 225;
```

the paddle state and the key to change their state:

```
var keyWPressed = false;
var keySPressed = false;
var keyArrowUpPressed = false;
var keyArrowDownPressed = false;

window.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 87) {
        keyWPressed = true;
        keySPressed = false;    // the player can hold down both keys at once, but 
                                // we want the last pressed key to take precedence
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 83) {
        keySPressed = true;
        keyWPressed = false;   // last keypress takes precedence
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 38) { // up arrow
        keyArrowUpPressed = true;
        keyArrowDownPressed = false;  // last keypress takes precedence
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 40) {  // down arrow
        keyArrowDownPressed = true;
        keyArrowUpPressed = false;  // last keypress takes precedence
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 82) {  // 'r'
        // when a player has won, hitting 'r' resets the game
        if (winner) {
            restartGame();
        }
    }
});
```

updating the paddle state and looping the game:

```
function update(){
    if (keyWPressed && leftHeight != 0){
        leftHeight = leftHeight - 5;
    }else if (keySPressed && leftHeight != 450){
        leftHeight = leftHeight + 5;
    }
    if (keyArrowUpPressed && rightHeight != 0){
        rightHeight = rightHeight - 5;
    }else if (keyArrowDownPressed && rightHeight != 450){
        rightHeight = rightHeight + 5;
    }
}

function gameloop(){
    update();
    draw();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameloop);
}
```

the problem is, whenever I press a key, for example, the W key, the paddle moves up at a single press when what I really want is for it to move only when the player is pressing and holding on to the W key.

Comment: So if you press, for example, the W key, the paddle moves up 5 pixels and then stops?

Comment: yeah, if it is only 1 press

Comment: If you console.log `keyWPressed` every frame, what happens after you press W for the first time? It should keep logging `true` - if it doesn't, you may be setting it to `false` elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Also, you should probably have the update function check if `leftHeight > 0`, not `leftHeight != 0` - it's safer for the update loop that way.

Comment: If you want it to continue to move, you probably want a while loop on a timer

Comment: what do you mean by safer?

Comment: and yeah it keeps logging true

Comment: but I want to be true only when the users is holding on to the W key, should I add a listener for key up to reset the state to false?

Comment: Safer just in the sense of accounting for more cases - right now, it'll only return true if `leftHeight` equals anything _except_ 0, and it sounds like you want it to be true if `leftHeight` is equal to anything _greater than_ 0. And yes, you should add a keyUp listener to reset to false - see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I added the keyUp listener and it's working perfectly now, thanks!